# A good reference for matrix completion

Tags: matrix, linear-algebra

Does anyone know a complete reference or book on matrix completion?

Comment: This is only a paper but looks decent at a glance and it's got Candes' material in the references. He is THE PERSON when it comes to matrix completion-factorization. I don't know of a whole book on it.  http://people.seas.harvard.edu/~minilek/cs229r/fall15/lec/lec22.pdf

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/matrix-completion